# Ogryns & two-handed weapon wielding

Tags: rogue-trader

Could an Ogryn use a regular two-handed weapon as a one handed weapon? For example, a chain axe.
Besides, how do you know which melee weapons are one handed or two handed? There is no such category in the weapon list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rogue Trader itself says nothing about any of your questions.  Ogryns aren't even mentioned at all there.  So I checked Only War.

Only War doesn't say anything about ogryns being able to use two-handed weapons one-handed, but I think it would be reasonable for the GM to allow on a case-by-case basis, given that ogryns start with Auto-Stabilized, Size (Hulking), and Unnatural Strength.

The individual weapon descriptions in Only War state "This is a one (or two) handed weapon.", but, for some reason, handedness is still not included in the weapon stats chart.

Comment: I am currently using these rules for Ogryns:
http://www.mediafire.com/view/t9o7f25ab4d1ruy/Ogryns%20as%20Player%20Characters.pdf

Should I stick with these or use Only War's rules?

Comment: Only War has the advantage of being an official product published by FFG and, personally, I think it looks better than the fan version you linked to, but, if you're happy with the fan version, then I don't think ogryn rules alone are sufficient reason to buy Only War (especially at FFG's prices).